# navBar not fading out

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script in order for the navBar to go in on certain place and disappear on that same place. I managed to make it go in, but it won't leave. I can't find my mistake. Please help me. Here is my code:

```
var dummie = document.getElementById("dummie");
var navBar = document.getElementById("navBar");

var test = function(){
    dummie.textContent = window.pageYOffset;

    if(window.pageYOffset > 351){
        navBar.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        if(window.pageYOffset < 351){
            navBar.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}

window.setInterval(test, 1);
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @SMcCrohan, Looks like it is not an HTML problem, just a bit of missing code.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `style` in your second line:

`navBar.visibility = "hidden";`

needs to be

`navBar.style.visibility = "hidden";`

Oh, and the place where you say

```
else {
    if(something){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

can be replaced by

```
else if(something){
    //Do something
}
```

which is a bit easier to type, and easier to read :).

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
navBar.visibility = "hidden";
```

You're missing `.style`, so it should be

```
navBar.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing [style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp), it should be

```
navBar.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

details referenece [style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

Comment: This was worded confusingly.